# Rectifiable Jordan curve with bad polygonal approximations

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves

This question is inspired by [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2216261/jordan-curve-theorem-for-rectifiable-curves) of mine. Is there an example of rectifiable Jordan curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$ such that, for some $\delta>0$, no polygonal path $\overline{\gamma(t_0)\gamma(t_1)\cdots\gamma(t_n)}$ with $0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n=1$ and $\max_{1\leq i\leq n}(t_i-t_{i-1})<\delta$, is a Jordan curve? According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2001884/aproximation-to-jordan-curve-by-polygonal-jordan-curve) question (with no answer yet), such curve $\gamma$ cannot be piecewise regular.

Answer (score 4):

Lemma 2 in the paper [Tverberg](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/jordan/tverberg.pdf) answers your question and the paper answers your first post, I think.